# How to delete matching directories recursively using Windows command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, regex

I've a folder `C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports\` and inside there are different folders but I want to delete only folders containing text say `192` in their names like

```
abc192     
xyz192     
pqr192xyz
```

apart from these there are also other folders.

To delete only matching folders with text `192`, I tried following -

```
rd /s /q C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports\*192*
```

But it results into `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Please suggest what is correct regex which will help to achieve this.

**NOTE** This is for Windows environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line using `cd /D folder && for /Directory /Recursive`

```bat
cd/d "%userprofile%\Desktop\htmlreports" && for /D /R  %i in (*192*)do rmdir /s /q "%~i"
```

[image] **[`For /D /R` Source](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

---

**1.** Go to your folder:

```bat
cd /D "C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports"
```

- Or, using one system variable:

```bat
cd /d "%userprofile%\Desktop\htmlreports"
```

---

**2.** Use **`&&`** operator

```bat
cd /D ... && for /D /R... do ...
```

**Obs.: 1**  Only if **`cd /D`** `return 0`, do the next `for /D /R` command
will be executed...

**Obs.: 2** You can add **`echo\`** to test and check the output before deleting any files/folders:

```bat
cd/d "%userprofile%\Desktop\htmlreports" && for /D /R  %i in (*192*)do echo\rmdir /s /q "%~i"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[CD](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[For /r](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[For /d](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution `&& ||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! And really appreciate your detailed explanation. Thanks a lot for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with cmd (`rd` will not work becuase it only can remove directories, use `del` as below):

```
del /s /q "C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports\*192*"
```

Try with powershell:

```
dir "C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports" -filter *192* | rm
```

Comment: Wasif, thanks for the answer but `del` only deletes files but not folders and your powershell command works but it asks for confirmation. `rm -f` with that command did not help to skip prompt. Actually I want to execute this through Jenkins pipeline starting powershell will be addition hence https://superuser.com/a/1580528/1156098 is perfect solution for me

Answer (score 0):

The **PowerShell** option:

```
$Source = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports'

Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory -Recurse | Where Name -match '192' | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Using aliases, we can shorten this to:

```
gci 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports' -ad -r | ? Name -match '192' | ri -r
```